# Error in set(new) : cannot change working directory on installation of SOfun

Tags: r, installation, package

I wanted to install  SOfun package on my new R 3.1.2 but it stopped with an error shown below.

```
devtools::install_github("mrdwab/SOfun")

WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages, but no version of Rtools compatible with R 3.1.2 was found. (Only the following incompatible version(s) of Rtools were found:3.2)

Please download and install Rtools 3.1 from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/ and then run find_rtools().
Downloading github repo mrdwab/SOfun@master
Installing SOfun

Error in set(new) : cannot change working directory
```

I would appreciate any suggestion to solve this error.

Comment: The error message explains how to solve it. Please read it. You need to upgrade Rtools.

Comment: Thanks,but the rtools I have now is the latest version and the error appears with both rtools 3.1 and 2.

Comment: How about `sudo chmod 777 [working_directory]` ?

Comment: Are you able to install other GitHub packages? I don't know that this is a SOfun-related issue.

Comment: Are you sure Rtools is in your PATH? Can you check whether it's in your System Environment Variables list?

Comment: Can you run `devtools::find_rtools(debug = TRUE)` and post the output as an edit to the question?

Comment: @AnandaMahto even under Windows, if you've got `cygwin` or equivalent installed, you can do that.  Alternatively, go via the painful "Properties" dialog box for the folder in question and "fix" the access rights.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I got the following with the command you suggested:  Scanning path...
Scanning registry...
Found c:/Rtools for 3.1 
Found c:/Rtools for 3.2 
VERSION.txt
Rtools version 3.1.0.1942 
[1] TRUE For your other query I just observed I cannot install other github packages. I have no administrative rights to the PC and rtools are installed in C drive

Comment: And now try installing SOfun again.

Comment: Still no luck. I get the same error message

Comment: Well, it doesn't answer your question, but maybe you can just try [installing from the zip file](https://github.com/mrdwab/SOfun/archive/master.zip) and see if that works.

Comment: I got the same error message with local installation.